# typescript debouncetime(2000) still fires the search immedately

Tags: typescript, angular7

I have the following methods in a component that implements OnInit, AfterViewInit. The trackFuzzySearchChanges is in the AfterViewInit(). No matter how much debouncetime is set, the method get executed immediately and executes loadData() that executes a WEB API getScreeningSummaries3() .  Please help.  Thanks.

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {

  this.dataSource.totalRecords$.subscribe(r => {
    this.paginator.length = r;
    this.totalRecords = this.paginator.length;
  });

  this.dataSource.pageNumber$.subscribe(n => {
    this.pageNumber = n;
  });

  this.dataSource.pageSize$.subscribe(n => {
    this.pageSize = n;
  });

  this.trackFuzzySearchChanges();
  this.trackFilterChanges();
  this.trackSortChanges();
  this.trackPaginatorChanges();
}
```

```js
trackFuzzySearchChanges() {
  merge(this.fuzzySearch.valueChanges)
    .pipe(
      tap(() => {
        debounceTime(2000), // fuzzy search changed when keyup for 2 sec in the mat-form-field
          distinctUntilChanged(),
          this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
        this.loadData();
      })
    ).subscribe();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling `debounceTime(2000)` and `distinctUntilChanged()` within `tap` operators callback. they should be piped in order to have actual effect. i also don't see any point of using `merge` opeartor as it is used for [turn multiple observables into a single onbservable](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html) try this way;

```
trackFuzzySearchChanges() {
  this.fuzzySearch.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(2000), // fuzzy search changed when keyup for 2 sec in the mat-form-field
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(() => {
        this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
        this.loadData();
      })
    ).subscribe();
}
```